# Date doesn't parse in Amazon Corretto 11.0.9.11.2

Tags: java, java-11, corretto

We've had a test start failing that checks if certain dates parse since upgrading from `amazon-corretto-11.0.7.10.1-windows-x64` to `amazon-corretto-11.0.9.11.2-windows-x64`.

I've written out a small example to show this. It passes in `11.0.7.10.1` and fails in `11.0.9.11.2`.

```
final String dateString = "16/08/2017 07:28:33 PM EST-05";

final DateTimeFormatterBuilder dateTimeFormatterBuilder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
dateTimeFormatterBuilder.parseCaseInsensitive();
dateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendPattern("d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss a zX");

final DateTimeFormatter formatter = dateTimeFormatterBuilder.toFormatter();

final OffsetDateTime parsedDate = OffsetDateTime.from(formatter.parse(dateString, new ParsePosition(0)));

System.out.println(parsedDate);
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '16/08/2017 07:28:33 PM EST-05' could not be parsed at index 23
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1916)
    at test.DateTest.main(DateTest.java:19)
```

Is this a bug in the JDK or something we're doing incorrectly?

**Corretto Issue**

https://github.com/corretto/corretto-11/issues/147

Comment: If it happened with the update and nothing else changed. You might just want to start off from release notes and validate if there were any changes related to the `Locale`s or providers.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how the openjdk unmodified versions behave, to see if it is a corretto specific thing.

Comment: I've updated my question with the Corretto issue I've created. Apparently it's happening on "multiple platforms and with multiple JDK vendor distributions"